# Sequelize - Multiple Op.Or operations for the same field

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How do I create a Sequelize filter that will check for multiple ranges of the same field.

In simple SQL query this would have been a straight forward thing to day but proves to be a bit tricky in Sequelize. I have tried few things but not getting the desired result with any of them

I am simplifying the code in this question because the actual code is very lengthy and has many parts that are not relevant to this question.

```
// This filter is added successfully
filters.advertised_price_weekly__c = { [Op.gt]: 0 }; 

// This filter 
filters.numberField = { 
[Op.Or]: [ 
  { [Op.gte]: 1, [Op.lte]: 3 }, 
  { [Op.gte]: 5, [Op.lte]: 7 },
  { [Op.gte]: 9, [Op.lte]: 11 } 
 ]
}


// Then call using the filter
    let options = {
      page: page, // Default 1
      paginate: limit, // Default 50
      attributes:  filterAttributes,
      where: filters,
    };

    return await this.query().paginate(options)
```

The query generated by Sequelize only doesn't include any of

```
AND "listing__c"."numberField" = 'NaN
```

The expected query should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE numberField>1 AND numberField<3 OR  numberField>5 AND numberField<9 OR  numberField>9 AND numberField<11
```

Comment: I think you have typo, it should be `[Op.or]` and not `[Op.Or]`, please change that and try to execute.

Comment: Actually this did the trick! Thanks for spotting it @VivekDoshi!

Answer (score 2):

**First Change `[Op.Or]` to `[Op.or]`** and try, and then you can try out the below once:

```
where: {
    $or: [
        {
            numberField : { [Op.between] : [1,3] },
        }, 
        {
            numberField : { [Op.between] : [5,7] },
        }, 
        {
            numberField : { [Op.between] : [9,11] },
        }
    ]
}
```

OR,

```
where: {
    numberField : {
        $or: [
            { [Op.between] : [1,3] },
            { [Op.between] : [5,7] },
            { [Op.between] : [9,11] },
        ]
    }
}
```

> **NOTE :** I havn't tried out the last one, but it should work

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Vivek, I tried it and still getting NaN in the SQL query it is generating...

```AND "listing__c"."geolocation__latitude__s" = 'NaN' AND "listing__c"."geolocation__longitude__s" = 'NaN'
```

Comment: My code looks like this now:

```
        filters.geolocation__latitude__s =
        {
          $or: [
          {
            geoLocationLat : { [Op.between] : 1, 3 ] },
          },
          {
            geoLocationLat : { [Op.between] : [5, 7 ] },
          }, 
          {
            geoLocationLat : { [Op.between] : [9, 11] },
          }
        ]}

```

Comment: @Siv, will you please accept and upvote the answer?